# Received status code 403 from server: VirusFound

Tags: nexus, gradlew, sonatype

Sonatype Nexus version 3.2.1-01

Multiple developers experiencing a problem downloading a file from Nexus during a gradlew build.

Below is the error encountered.

I am able to download the file via curl or wget without error.

Any ideas what the problem is or where to look?

> What went wrong:
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':collection:testCompile'.
>   Could not download accessors-smart.jar (net.minidev:accessors-smart:1.1)
>   Could not get resource 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/net/minidev/accessors-smart/1.1/accessors-smart-1.1.jar'.
>   Could not GET 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/net/minidev/accessors-smart/1.1/accessors-smart-1.1.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: VirusFound

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my problem by adding the following line in my gradle.properties file.

systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1|localhost|1XX.XXX.XXX.XXX